# How do I search and replace across multiple lines with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

```
$ perl --version
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

$ echo -e "foo\nbar" > baz.txt
$ perl -p -e 's/foo\nbar/FOO\nBAR/m' baz.txt
foo
bar
```

How can I get this replacement to work?

Comment: Try adding the `g` flag: `'s/foo\nbar/FOO\nBAR/gm'`.

Comment: @Jerry no, the `g` option is for global behavior and is not relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `-0` switch to change the input separator:

```
perl -0777pe 's/foo\nbar/FOO\nBAR/' baz.txt
```

`-0777` sets the separator to `undef`, `-0` alone sets it to `\0` which might work for text files not containing the null byte.

Note that `/m` is needless as the regex does not contain `^` nor `$`.

Comment: Much better than mine. I'm not used to `-0` switch but in this case suits perfectly. **+1** for that.

Comment: `-0` sets `$/` to `"\000"` and `-0777` to `undef`, but both do file slurp. :o

Comment: @Сухой27, no. `-0` only slurps the file if it doesn't contain NUL characters. Text files normally don't contain those characters. So for text files it will generally not make a difference, but if you want to slurp the file in regardless of what it may contain, that's `-0777` you want. `-0` is more for processing the output of `find -print0` or `grep -lZ` (NUL delimited records). Compare `printf 'a\0b\0' | perl -l -0 -ne 'print $.'` with `printf 'a\0b\0' | perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $.'`

Comment: You'd use `-0`/`-z`/`--null` with GNU `grep` or GNU `sed` because you don't have any other choice there. They don't have a slurp mode, but you can emulate it with `-z` as long as you can guarantee the input doesn't contain NUL characters. (you can still use `pcregrep -M ...` or `gsed ':1;$!{N;b1}...` though)

Comment: Another difference between `-0` and `-0777` is that for an empty `baz.txt`, You get 0 records with the former and 1 empty record for the latter (doesn't make a difference here for `s/foo\nbar/FOO\nBAR/` but would for instance for `s/^/prefix/`).

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with the `-p` switch. It reads input one line at a time. So you cannot run a regexp against a newline between two lines because it will never match. One thing you can do is to read all input modifying variable `$/` and apply the regexp to it. One way:

```
perl -e 'undef $/; $s = <>; $s =~ s/foo\nbar/FOO\nBAR/; print $s' baz.txt
```

It yields:

```
FOO
BAR
```