# Replace string in shell using sed or Perl?

Tags: perl, shell, replace, sed

How can I replace the following string:

```
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>1234</value>
```

And make it to be:

```
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>0</value>
```

Please take into account that there is a line break.

Comment: Are you wondering about string replacement in general, or [replacement across multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742526/how-to-search-and-replace-across-multiple-lines-with-perl)?

Comment: Is it exactly 1234 or is that just representative of a digit string?  Is the replacement always zero?  What have you tried?

Comment: [It looks like you are trying to parse XML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/725418) Would you like to try [an XML parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) instead?

Comment: About replacement across multiple lines. I have tried sed '/<value>-myValue.*/ {N; s/-myValue.*<value>\./-myValue.*value>0</g}' filename

Comment: If this is indeed XML, sed is not a good tool to process it. Consider using xmlstarlet, e.g. `xmlstarlet ed -u '//value[.="-myValue"]/following-sibling::value[1]' -v 0 filename.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Script

```
sed -e '/<value>-myValue</,/<value>/{ /<value>[0-9][0-9]*</ s/[0-9][0-9]*/0/; }' data
```

From a line containing `<value>-myValue<` to the next line containing `<value>`, if the line matches `<value>XX<` where XX is a string of one or more digits, replace the string of digits with `0`.

#### Input

```
This is not something to change
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>1234</value>
<value>myValue</value>
          <value>1234</value>
nonsense
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>abcd</value>
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>4321</value>
stuffing
```

#### Output

```
This is not something to change
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>0</value>
<value>myValue</value>
          <value>1234</value>
nonsense
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>abcd</value>
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>0</value>
stuffing
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is XML, TLP is right that an XML parser would be superior.  Continuing on with your `sed` approach, however, consider:

```
$ sed '/<value>-myValue/ {N; s/<value>[[:digit:]]\+/<value>0/}' file
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>0</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly simplify this a bit, depending on what criteria you specifically want to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' )->parse( \*DATA );
foreach my $value ( $twig->findnodes('//value') ) {
    if (    $value->trimmed_text eq '-myValue'
        and $value->next_sibling('value')
        and $value->next_sibling('value')->text =~ m/^\d+$/ )
    {
        $value->next_sibling('value')->set_text('1234');

    }
}

$twig->print;

__DATA__
<root>
<value>-myValue</value>
          <value>0</value>
          </root>
```

This outputs:

```
<root>
  <value>-myValue</value>
  <value>1234</value>
</root>
```

- It parses your XML.
- Looks for all nodes with a tag of `value`.
- Checks that it has a sibling.
- Checks that sibling is 'just numeric' e.g. matching regex `^\d+$`
- replaces the content of that sibling with `1234`.

And will work on XML regardless of formatting, which is the problem with XML - pretty fundamentally there's a bunch of entirely valid things you can do that are semantically identical in XML.