# Sed combine only certain lines within directory

Tags: sed

I am using sed to combine lines of text files in a directory.
The command cd dir && sed -e 'N;s/\n//' *.txt works fine to do that but is there any way it can be tweaked to only combine the line sentences that start with ** with following sentence ending in **. So

```
This is Line1    
**This is Line2    
This is Line3**    
This is Line4    
This is Line5
```

Becomes

```
This is Line1    
** This is Line2 This is Line3**    
This is Line4    
This is Line5
```

etc

Comment: are there empty lines between Line2 and Line3 or is it just formatting issue in example shown?

Comment: No empty lines just the formatting.

Comment: Is the issue to match a special 2 lines of text OR the specific line numbers? Good luck.

Comment: Just to match a special 2 lines of text and I realized in the file there are a few blank spaces between paragraphs but no blank lines between the special two lines if that makes a difference

Comment: so, haven't any of the answers worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I received error message unexpected EOF (pending }'s) when I tried commands.

Comment: that answer was updated.. if you still get an error, you could give details on which sed version you are using.. as well as try that particular example input file to be sure.. and what about other answers? do they give error as well?

Comment: Can you have lines that start with `**` but the next line **doesn't** end in `**` (or vice-versa) either at the start/end of the file or with other lines in between or....? If so, what should happen with those cases (include them in your sample input/output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. This will do what you show with your sample input/output:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(/^\*\*/?FS:RS)}1' file
This is Line1
**This is Line2 This is Line3**
This is Line4
This is Line5
```

but of course it doesn't address any of the requirements you haven't shared with us yet (e.g. what to do when a line starts with ** but the next line doesn't end with ** or vice-versa or a line starts and ends with ** or a line starting with ** is at the end of the input file or....).

Comment: This works better thank you is there anyway to close the gap between "**This is Line2       This is Line3**" to make it into one solid sentence?

Comment: Of course, change `FS` to `""`, but if that's what you wanted then why did you show a gap as the desired output in your question?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion didn't realized I did that above.

Comment: I looked more into awk why is it when I try to save the changes to the actual file using that command above instead to stdout using the >> redirection it continues to prompt me for input?

Comment: Are you asking why `command file >> file` (where `command` is awk in this case but could be any command) doesn't work? What are you hoping it'll do? If you want the output of a command written to the file you used as input, that's `command file > tmp && mv tmp file`. If you try to write to the same file you are reading the shell can do whatever it likes, including emptying the file before the command reads the first line from it. Some tools (e.g. perl, GNU sed, GNU awk) have options to do "inplace editing" but they really just use a tmp file internally too.

Comment: Right now the changes only saves to stdout, I am trying to save the changes to the actual file. So when I open the file I see the changes not just the original copy.

Comment: Did you read my whole comment? If so and you still have a question then post a new question to SO complete with sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/^\*\*/{:loop; N; /\*\*$/{s/\n/ /g;p;d;}; b loop}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
This is Line1
**This is Line2
in between
This is Line3**
This is Line4
**This is Line5
This is Line6**

$ sed '/^\*\*/{:loop; N; /\*\*$/{s/\n/ /g;p;d;}; b loop;}' file
This is Line1
**This is Line2 in between This is Line3**
This is Line4
**This is Line5 This is Line6**
```

Comment: When running command I get error code 1 "unexpected EOF (pending }'s).

Comment: There are blank lines which should be kept intact?

Comment: @NickJ, Updated answer.

Comment: @sjsam, OP said that there is no blank lines. It's just formatting.

Comment: I had to correct my statement there are blank lines within the document between paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Sed is your friend

```
$ sed '/^\*\*/{:l1;/\*\*$/!{N;bl1};s/\n/ /g;}' file
This is Line1

**This is Line2  This is Line3**

This is Line4

This is Line5
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
This is Line1
**This is Line2
This is Line3**
This is Line4
This is Line5 

$ # this slurps entire file
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/^(\*\*.*)\n(.*\*\*)$/$1 $2/mg' ip.txt 
This is Line1
**This is Line2 This is Line3**
This is Line4
This is Line5 

$ # can use this if testing start of line for ** is enough
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ / if /^\Q**/' ip.txt
```

Reference: [How do I search and replace across multiple lines with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742526/how-to-search-and-replace-across-multiple-lines-with-perl)