# Regex not capturing newlines when used in sed or perl

Tags: html, regex, perl, csv, sed

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to clean, and part of that is removing HTML tags inside some of the values. I came across this solution: `sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' file.html` from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file).

Before trying it out, I tested the regex (`/<[^>]*>/g`) using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/). I used the following as my text sample:

```
<asd>
< asd >
< asdsad
 adsad >
```

On RegExr, all three tags are matched, however, when I use the sed command to remove the tags, the third tag remains, i.e. I'm left with:

```
< asdsad
 adsad >
```

I need to be able to remove multiline tags as well, as many of the tags in the CSV I'm attempting to clean have attributes with quotes, like `class="some-class-name"`, and those quotes are messing with the CSV formatting.

I've also tried a Perl command, as Perl is supposed to have better multiline handling. I tried `perl -pe 's/<[^>]*>//g' file`, but it had the same result as sed.

EDIT: To address concerns of a possible duplicate, my question was based around why one Regex engine ([RegExr](http://regexr.com/)) was capturing different entities than another (sed and Perl) and how to get those others to display the first's results. The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742526/how-do-i-search-and-replace-across-multiple-lines-with-perl)'s answer happened to solve my problem, although the question came from a different (yet similar) place.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Strip/Strip.pm

Answer (score 0):

For clarity I'll post the answer here, from @LukStorms' comment. Answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742526/how-do-i-search-and-replace-across-multiple-lines-with-perl).

TL;DR: The `-0` flag solved the issue, at least with Perl.

Full command: `perl -0pe 's/<[^>]*>//g' file`